# Order of evaluation of Exp and Normal on result from Series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, series-expansion, core-language

This may be more math related than *Mathematica* related, but I thought this might be of interest to the group.

I'm trying to work with some Taylor Series approximations of functions that are ultimately exponentiated. I've noticed that the order which I apply `Normal` and `Exp` affects the output, but I don't understand why.

Here's an example

```
Series[-q (c[x1]  - c[x2]), {x2, x1, 1}]
Exp[%] // Normal // Simplify
(Exp[%% // Normal]) // Simplify
```

The output is

> ```
> SeriesData[x2, x1, {q*Derivative[1][c][x1]}, 1, 2, 1]
> 1 + q*(-x1 + x2)*Derivative[1][c][x1]
> E^(q*(-x1 + x2)*Derivative[1][c][x1])
> ```

Assuming that we are dealing with real functions and parameters, it seems like the `Exp[%% // Normal]` would be more accurate since we can derive the `Exp[%] // Normal` result from it when `q` is close to zero.

Can anyone explain why I get these differences?

Answer (score 4):

Shown is the actual output visible on the screen.

```
z = Series[-q (c[x1] - c[x2]), {x2, x1, 1}] 
(* q c'[x1] (x2 - x1) + O[x2 - x1]^2 *)

Exp[z] // Normal // Simplify 
(* 1 + q (-x1 + x2) c'[x1] *)

(Exp[z // Normal]) // Simplify
(* E^(q (-x1 + x2) c'[x1]) *)
```

The third expression `Exp[z // Normal]` converts the `Series` to normal linear expression and then exponentiates it, as expected.

In the second expression, the `Series` function is still active (because `Normal` has not yet been applied to it) and applies itself to all of Exp[...], as it is supposed to do, and only then does `Normal` convert it to a normal expression.  In other words, it is performing

```
Series[Exp[-q (c[x1] - c[x2])], {x2, x1, 1}] 
(* 1 + q (-x1 + x2) c'[x1] *)
```

and only then applying `Normal`.  See the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/O.html) for `O` for a very relevant example.

Throughout, `Simplify` does not add much.